# How to work around laptop graphics card failure?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, expresscard

I've got an old IBM R52 laptop who's graphics card just completely failed. Is there any way to get a graphics card that plugs into the Expresscard slot? I'm not talking about the ViDock, but a graphics card that is actually designed to function in the Express Card slot.

Comment: They do sell expresscard graphic cards they are just expensive. http://www.techradar.com/news/computing-components/graphics-cards/how-to-make-an-external-laptop-graphics-adaptor-915616 you might be better of just getting a new laptop ( you will spend more on the hardware to do this ) then you will on a new laptop.

Comment: Buy a new Laptop.

Comment: The new laptop comes in about one year when I go to college.

Comment: I don't think there's something like a pluggable video card that will automatically work with your laptop monitor. I guess that's what you want, if you don't want Vidock or any USB card solutions.